# Changing background color in a activity.

Tags: android

I used Android Studio to create basic activity using New -> Activity -> Basic Activity. But the activity background colour is black. I know it is to reduce battery consumption. But is there a way to change it to white colour, without changing style.

I tried to change the background colour of the root layout, but then it won't show hint text of edit text field. Because it's colour is white.

Then I tried to change theme from Material to Material Lite, then it wouldn't show the change when I run the app in the device.

[image]

Here is the activity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".SearchBus"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_search_bus"
    android:parentActivityName=".MapsActivity"
    >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="uk.co.stableweb.iroute.MapsActivity" />
</activity>
```

Comment: "Then I tried to change theme from Material to Material Lite, then it wouldn't show the change when I run the app in the device." Try cleaning and rebuilding your project. If that still doesn't work, completely uninstall your app from the device. Usually when changes don't appear to work, it means there is a problem with the build and install process.

Comment: Your theme is not set to 'material light' from the screenshot for the Android Studio designer.  If it was, it would abbreviate it as "light"

Comment: No, I changed back to material to show my current situation.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks! I will try it.

Comment: The theme you set in that designer view, on the toolbar, doesn't effect the theme your app runs with.  It merely lets you see how your app would appear if matched against a certain theme.

Comment: "I tried to change theme from Material to Material Lite" How did you do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your `styles.xml` set the `android:windowBackground` attribute for whatever theme you are using for application or activity.  You can find the theme you are using in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

   <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/somecolor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Note: If you have views in your layout that aren't transparent, it will block you from seeing the color you set here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :`android:background="#ffffff"` i? It works for me

Comment: Setting android:background in the theme will overwrite anything with a background, not just the main background (e.g. button frames, etc)